# How's the android directory structure?

Tags: android

How the directories are disposed? Where do I copy my musics and pictures in my virtual device to test my apps?

**update:** trying with mTools....
**update:** mtools fails... cant download it to virtual device..

**update:** I entered the internet on the Android's virtual device, tried to save an image, and it says that "An SD card is required". I thought I've read in the android.developers.com that the device has a SD card by default.. Anyway, I'll look for how to create it..

Comment: So, just to check the obvious: does the source file actually exist? Are you working from a Linux host?

Comment: @Pontus Yes, it do exist, and I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 using Android 2.2 API 8

Comment: @Pontus Gagge everything is local, nothing remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest SDK (API level 8, equalling 2.2), you use [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html).

Comment: The DIRECTORY_PICTURES attribute have the value "Pictures", but trying to copy with 'adb push' throws: failed to copy '/home/wellington/housemd.jpg' to '/Pictures/housemd.jpg[A': No such file or directory

Comment: So, are you calling getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)?

Comment: ops, ok, now I did it right, but still got: failed to copy '/home/wellington/housemd.jpg' to '/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/housemd.jpg': No such file or directory

Comment: I'm in the sdk tools folder, but I believe it makes no difference, as I'm specifying the full path..

Comment: The problem was I had no sdcard on the virtual device.. XD

Answer (score 0):

Usually, music and pictures will live anywhere in the `/sdcard` folder. Keep in mind that not all handsets provide an SD Card.

Comment: I've tried to copy a file usin adb push, but a got: failed to copy '/home/wellington/housemd.jpg' to '/sdcard/media/housemd.jpg': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to try to use an emulated sdcard, then you have to use the mksdcard utility. It's covered here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#mksdcard

You'll want to create an avd that points to the .img file you created. Once the avd is started, you can then use adb push to put files on it.

Comment: or, when creating the virtual device in AVD Manager, just mark the box to create the sdcard.. ;)